# Should I create an interface for every class to make my code testable (unit testing)

Tags: unit-testing, testing, interface

I'm trying to learn how to create valuable unit tests.
In each tutorial I saw people create interfaces for every dependency to create a mock.

Is it mean that I should always create an interface for every class I have in my project? I don't know is it a good or a bad idea but every time I see a rule with "always" I get suspicious.

Comment: YAGNI. You aren't going to need it. Just do what you need for current problem. You can always add interface later if you need. Btw, you DO NOT need interface to make your code testable.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question for SO. Perhaps multiple answers are possible, then place them below and vote on it.

Comment: It seems you're reading tutorials from 10 or more years ago, when mocking frameworks could only mock interfaces. That's not the case anymore, and for a loooong time.

Comment: @JBNizet If I want to mock a class then I will need to make methods I want to mock virtual

Comment: It depends on your language and mocking framework.

Comment: @JBNizet C# and Moq. It also requires parameterless constructor

Comment: So you found the answer...

Comment: @JBNizet So should I create interfaces or mark methods as virtual and provide parameterless constructor? Which is a good practice?

Comment: @user4230877: Both are, depending on what you're doing and how it needs to work with everything else you're building.  We can't stress this enough... There is no one single correct way to write all possible code.

Comment: Don't you think among other information the language you use would be relevant?

Comment: @Olaf What do you mean? That I should change language?

Comment: @user4230877 You should not have skipped the **mandatory** [tour]. And [ask] is also relevant for you.

Answer (score 2):

> I should always create an interface for every class I have in my project?

No.

There's no one single rule you can follow or thing you can do which would make all of your code automatically unit-testable.  What you *can* do is write code with abstractable dependencies.  If you want to test whether or not the code you've written is easily unit testable, try to write a unit test for it.  If a dependency gets in your way, you have a coupled dependency.  Abstract it.

*How* you abstract it is up to you.  You have a variety of tools at your disposal:

1. Interfaces
2. Abstract classes
3. Concrete classes with lots of `virtual` members
4. Mockable pass-through wrapper classes (very useful for non-unit-testable 3rd party dependencies)
5. etc.

You also have a variety of ways to get the dependency into the code that uses it:

1. Constructor injection
2. Property injection
3. Passing it to the method as an argument
4. Factories
5. In some circumstances, service locators (useful when introducing dependency abstraction to a legacy codebase, for example)
6. etc.

How you structure you code really depends on what you're building and what makes sense for those objects.  For a service class which integrates with an external system, an interface makes a lot of sense.  For a domain model which has a variety of potential implementations that share functionality, an abstract class may make a lot of sense.  There are many possibilities for many potential uses.

The real litmus test of whether or not your code is unit-testable isn't "do I use interfaces?", it's "can I write a meaningful unit test for this?"  If the functionality is isolatable without relying on dependencies (either by not having them or by allowing them to be mocked for testing), then it seems pretty unit-testable to me.